# Document list detached from application

Tags: listview, document, file-listing

I have the problem that by the document list got detached from the application and was floating freely.

I wanted to stick it back into the application, it only snapped at the top. But in this Horizontal format it is not readable and completely useless.

Can somebody help me, and tell me how to put it back in the vertical part of the application window on the left border ?